# How to add Values in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hey there I'm new to Swift and in this Community so sorry for my stupid question. Im trying to create a little quiz app with an UILabel for the Question and a tableView for the Answers.

I found a solution to show the Question in the UILabel but I don't have any idea how to put the Answers in the Cell from my UITabelView.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    struct Question {
        var id: Int
        var questionText: String
        var answers: [String]
        var correctAnswer: Int
    }
    var question1 = Question(id: 1, questionText: "Foo?", answers:["1", "2", "3", "4"], correctAnswer: 2)
    var question2 = Question(id: 2, questionText: "Bar?", answers:["1", "2", "3", "4"], correctAnswer: 2)
    var question3 = Question(id: 3, questionText: "Baz?", answers:["1", "2", "3", "4"], correctAnswer: 2)

    

    @IBOutlet weak var answerView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    
    var listITemArray:[String] = Array()
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        setupButtonn()
       
       // answers.append("Aleks")
       // answers.append("Stefan")
       // answers.append("Nico")
        
        answerView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CheckMarkCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CheckListIdentifier")
        answerView.dataSource = self
        answerView.delegate = self
        
        questionLabel.text = question5.questionText
        listITemArray.
        
        
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listITemArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckListIdentifier") as! CheckMarkCell
        cell.answerLabel.text = listITemArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: If you want to reload tableView each time you change ArrayList data, please use:

var listITemArray: [String] = [] {
  didSet {
    answerView.reloadData()
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You need to append values to your array. You have initialised the array but you are not adding values to it. Secondly you can do this by using button tag or using closure. I will attached answer if you want

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H5YF-dKYq2fFwY4FfYMYw-QZCZp3AQ38?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey Muhammad, could you please Upload the File Again for me? Tanks in front

Answer (score 0):

`listITemArray` is currently an empty array as you have not populated any data into it here`var listITemArray:[String] = Array()` so `listITemArray.count` would return zero and therefore zero cells on your tableView.